# Javascript Drag and Drop: removing dragged element following successful drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using the native *drag and drop* API in javascript.  How can I remove a dragged element from the DOM following a successful drop?

- I've tried listening to the **drop** event, but this only gets fired on the element which is dropped onto and has no reference to the element being dragged.
- I've tried listening to the **dragend** element, but this doesn't let me know whether a drop was successful or not.
- I'm trying to avoid storing the element being dragged in a global variable as this will cause problems if a drag occurs between different tabs or browsers.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KNG6n/3/

A list of letters which can be dragged into the box.  When a letter's node is dropped on the box, I'd like it to be removed from the list (without effecting any other list items containing the same letter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Listen for the dragend event and check the dropEffect variable of the dataTransfer object before doing anything with the dragged element:

```
htmlElement.addEventListener('dragend', function(event){
    if(event.dataTransfer.dropEffect !== 'none'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Apparently dropEffect will always be none in Chrome on Windows, the bug report has been open for years: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39399

Answer (score 7):

Also take a look at this example: http://html5demos.com/drag

> var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
>
> ```
> el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
> ```

Comment: This solution only works if all the elements have ids (which mine don't).  Also, it means you have to set the data to be the id, rather than something useful.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to assign this to a variable scoped outside of the dragstart, and use that element when dropped.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KNG6n/5/)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid storing the element being dragged in a global variable as this will cause problems if a drag occurs between different tabs or browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You get the drop position of element in the **dragend** event. You can find if an droppable element is present at that position.

You can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`